# Can I get the data I want from the latest data from Redis?

Tags: java, redis, lettuce

I want to know offset from Redis data, like offset in kafka consumer.
The code below is the code that uses Kafka Consumer and offset to import the latest n data.

```
public ConsumerRecords<String, String> getLatestMessages() {
    ConsumerRecords<String, String> messages = null;
    consumer.seekToEnd(topics);

    long endPosition = consumer.position(topicPartition);
    long startPosition = endPosition - 10; 

    consumer.seek(topicPartition, startPosition);
    messages = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100));

    return messages;
}
```

Can I get n data from Redis like this code?

Similar method was seen in the sorted set, but it was not the function I wanted. 
I want to store the mass log in real time to Redis, and I want to bring them to the latest 10~50 data every 100ms.

Is there any way I can get it from Redis? 
Now I use lettuce library.

Answer (score 0):

With the pub and sub feature in the redis, you can store your data in one place and withdraw this data at specific intervals.

You can subscribe your data to mongodb with stackexcahnge.redis and submit it to your clients with an api

There may be other solutions but i am using it like that and would recommend